# React - Passing data counter from child to parents component

Tags: reactjs

so, im just learning about props method and i want to try how to passing data from child to parent component.

im trying to make counter app, when click + the counter increasing and click - the counter decreasing

**i have parent component like this**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ComponentB from './ComponentB'

const ComponentA = () => {
    const [counterB , setCounterB] = useState(0);

    


    return( 
        <div>
            <h1>ComponentB</h1>
            <h3>{counterB}</h3>
            <ComponentB
            add={counterB => setCounterB(counterB)}
            subtract={counterB => setCounterB(counterB)}/>
        </div> );
    
}
 
export default ComponentA;
```

**and child component like this**

```
import React from 'react';

const ComponentB = (props) =>{
    return(
        <div>
        <button onClick={()=> props.add(+1)}>+</button>
        <button onClick={()=> props.subtract(-1)}>-</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ComponentB
```

Comment: Why are the methods to operate on the value that is being passed from parent to child set in the parent here? In React, you want to keep state closest to where it's being operated on. Passing the value to be incremented or decremented from parent to child makes sense, but passing down the logic to do that incrementing or decrementing (in this simple example, anyway) doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
return( 
    <div>
        <h1>ComponentA</h1>
        <h3>{counterB}</h3>
        <ComponentB
        add={diff => setCounterB(counterB + diff)}
        subtract={diff => setCounterB(counterB + diff)}/>
    </div> );
```

you pass the function `diff => setCounterB(counterB + diff)` to `ComponentB` as `prop.add`. This function sets the state of `counterB` to the first argument of that function. So when the button invokes `props.add(+1)}` the value of `counterB` is set to `1` every time it is pressed.

What you want is to add `+1` to the state of `counterB`. Thus you should it this way:

```js
// Get a hook function - only needed for this Stack Snippet
const {useState} = React;

const ComponentA = () => {
    const [counterB , setCounterB] = useState(0);

    return( 
        <div>
            <h1>ComponentA</h1>
            <h3>{counterB}</h3>
            <ComponentB
            add={diff => setCounterB(counterB + diff)}
            subtract={diff => setCounterB(counterB + diff)}/>
        </div> );
    
}

const ComponentB = (props) =>{
    return(
        <div>
        <button onClick={()=> props.add(+1)}>+</button>
        <button onClick={()=> props.subtract(-1)}>-</button>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ComponentA/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to create a method in the Parent component to update the state given a value received from the child.

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
    this.updateCountWithValue = this.updateCountWithValue.bind(this);
  }

  updateCountWithValue(value) {
    let count = this.state.count;
    count += value;
    this.setState({
      count: count
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{`Count: ${this.state.count}`}</h1>
        <Child updateCount={this.updateCountWithValue} value={1} />
        <Child updateCount={this.updateCountWithValue} value={-1} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.updateCount(this.props.value)}>
          {this.props.value}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, the props of my `Child` component are:

1. The value that the child will update or change
2. A method to update the `Parent` component.

I made this sample so you can see how it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/child-to-parent-uvfmi?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
<ComponentB
   add={counterB => setCounterB(counterB)}
   subtract={counterB => setCounterB(counterB)}/>
```

Try this:

```
<ComponentB
   add={val => setCounterB(counterB+val)}
   subtract={val => setCounterB(counterB+val)}/>   // using '+' coz val = -1
```